# if conditions avoid repetitions

Tags: java, if-statement

I have three if conditions something like below

```
if ((class1.getMethod1().subString(0,1) == "1") && !class1.getMethod1().subString(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase(str1.subString(0,1))
if ((class1.getMethod1().subString(0,1) == "2") && !class1.getMethod1().subString(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase(str1.subString(0,1))
if ((class1.getMethod1().subString(0,1) == "3") && !class1.getMethod1().subString(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase(str1.subString(0,1))
```

All the if conditions are gonna do same stuff. Is there anyway I can avoid repeating these many if conditions and make it in a single line ?

Comment: maybe make a method call out of it? `if(myCondition(class1, "1")){}`

Comment: How about a `switch` statement?

Comment: get the substring first and do the comarison on the substring (`String substring = class1.getMethod1().subString(,01); ... substring.equals("1"); ...`). And [never compare objects via `==` unless you exactly know what you are doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus).

Comment: This Kind of question is about code Review and should be ask at [codereview.SE]

Answer (score 2):

Actually you have different == check for the subString to match with either case "1", "2" or "3". So you can write like this

```
if(((class1.getMethod1().subString(0,1) == "1") 
  || (class1.getMethod1().subString(0,1) == "2") 
  || (class1.getMethod1().subString(0,1) == "3"))
  && !class1.getMethod1().subString(0,1).equalsIgnoreCase(str1.subString(0,1))
```

The above will make it in single line